# How to store JWT Token in authorization header in Aspnet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect

I have an "Auth Service" application in .Net Core which authenticates via a Challenge Request and then redirects back to the client application with a token.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("Login")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = returnUrlQs
        }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

Currently I transmit the token through a HTTP cookie using the `options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` OpenId Connect event. However the 4kb cookie length is too small and so I want to try move it to the authorization header.

I've tried setting the Response header but it's not received on the other side; on the client app.

Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Setting request headers is the client's job, not the API's.
So your back-end can't set those.
You'll need to return the token so that code on your front-end can get it and then assign it as a request header on future requests.

Another option here might be to do the OpenID Connect authentication from your front-end application (depending on what your identity provider supports).
This way it would get tokens and have the ability to refresh them, and your API could focus on just validating tokens in requests.

Answer (score 0):

Put your token inside the body of response and include [Authorize] attribute.
eg:

```
//in your api
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("update")]
private IActionResult update([FromBody] Model model){
//do some actions here
}
```

and in your client side, you store your token via session or any temporary storage then retrieve it if necessary and put it in your header.
do something like this:

```
  //in your client
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/update",
  data: {someParameter: "some value"},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  Authorization : "Bearer " + yourToken,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    //some code
  }
});
```

i did not test this code but only to give you some idea.

Comment: This looks on the right track, is there any way to grab the token from within the API method?

Comment: @user3167162 yes but you need to store it in your database along side with your user who logged in so that you can fetch the token from db

Comment: @user3167162 its either you get the token in api through response body or you can insert your jwt in db with userid who logged on and fetch it later when needed.

Comment: Thanks @jean but I think you missed my question. If I have a REST API with an [Authorize] tag is there a way to fetch the token from within the method so that I can return it in the Response body?

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with the 4Kb limit, then you should put our token on a diet and reduce its size by removing unnecessary claims.

Comment: We might more than 4kb to store authorization information.

Comment: Usually you really don't need to store that much in the token, instead you can lookup or cache the less frequently accessed information like profile data when needed.